# Oyster as a criminal

Tags: meaning, slang

In Dickensian, Mrs. Gamp doesn't like the Midlands, as they are rampant with cracksmen, oysters  and dippers.

I managed to find cracksman and dipper in Merriem-Webster, but who is an oyster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that the transcriber of this episode misheard ***hoister***<sup>†</sup>, which Partridge, [*A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*, 8th ed., 1984, p. 559](https://books.google.com/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PA559&lpg=PA559&dq=hoister+shop-lifter&source=bl&ots=_2OAgNpKZJ&sig=cZeaerLFs8HxN4148B6mZKchnJA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLwJS8ntXKAhVI4mMKHfVrDoQQ6AEIPTAG#v=onepage&q=hoister&f=false)
gives as a slang term from the 18th century into the 20th for a shoplifter.

---

<sup>†</sup> Or the actor playing Mrs. Gamp may have used a dialect in which the /h/ is dropped.

Comment: Brilliant theory.

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?

Comment: @GoDucks Absolutely. Knowing the new OED (which I don't have access to) doesn't have *oyster* in a relevant sense made it pretty sure that we should be looking for something else.

Answer (score 2):

Some sort of a petty criminal, given (a) the next line is *Well, rather a few petty criminals than a murderer on the loose* and (b) that *oyster* is placed in a list  of petty criminals in between *cracksman* (burglar or safe-cracker) and a *dipper* (pickpocket), definitions found in Merriam-Webster.

The *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED) has no record of *oyster* as any sort of petty criminal.

In the seven volume *[Slang and Its Analogues Past and Present](https://books.google.com/books?id=prATAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=slang+and+its+analogues&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiogrPPkNXKAhWC1CYKHQPSAGUQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=oyster&f=false)*, there is also no entry for *oyster* that refers to a petty criminal.

It could be an erroneous or one-off use. If Dickens had actually used it to mean *a criminal* it seems one or both of the above resources would list it as such.

Or you could write the BBC and/or the authors of the script and ask them what they meant.

Comment: Dickens doesn't use any of these terms in *Martin Chuzzlewit*. *Dickensian* is a present-day pastiche.